# grep a file with a list of regular expressions

Tags: regex, grep

I have a large file of regular expressions, one per line.  I would like to inverse grep another multi-line file against any regular expression that appears in the first file.  Something like this:

```
grep -v fileWithManyRegularExpressions fileThatMightMatchSomeRegularExpressions
```

Is there an elegant method to do this aside from looping through every regular expression?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
grep -v -f regexes.txt content.txt
```

Comment: just remember that -v is applied AFTER any matches, so effectively it's negation of the union of regexs, not the union of the negatives of regexs.

Comment: So `grep -v -f` corresponds to "None of the regexes match content" and `grep -f` is "One or many regexes match content". These certainly seem like the most common usecases by far. What would union of negatives mean?

Comment: @StevenLu a union of negatives would be "One or more of the regexes did not match content". It is equivalent to the negation of "All these regexes matched the content". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 3):

At least with Gnu grep you can use `--file=<filename>` and all should be well.